# Pattern based file selection and deletion in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, file, selection, subversive

What I'm trying to is tag a batch of files for deletion within Eclipse, prior to issuing a commit via the Subversive integration to "delete" these files from the repository.

In a trivial case, you can of course do this by selecting multiple files in the explorer, alt-clicking and selecting delete, prior to doing a commit.

However, I need to do this on ~500 files that are spread across a directory hierarchy six+ levels deep.

As such, I'm wondering if there's any way to select and perform the standard alt-click operations on a group of files matching a given pattern, or indeed whether this is the best approach in the first instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Eclipse main menu bar, select Search > File.  Leave the "Containing Text" field blank, and enter the file name pattern you want.

This will display the files you're interested in in the Search view.  To delete them:

- In the view menu of the Search view (icon is a downward-pointing triangle, just to the left of the minimise/maximise buttons), select "show as list" instead of "show as tree". This hides directories from the Search view, and shows only the files which matched the pattern.
- Select all files in the Search view with Ctrl-A
- Right-click the selected files and choose Show In > Navigator from the popup menu. All matched files are now selected in the Navigator view.
- Right-click one of the selected files in the Navigator, and choose Delete.

Comment: This will show the files in the search results tab, but how can I then delete them?

Comment: @middaparka: My mistake, I assumed you could delete files directly from the search results. I've expanded the answer, it should give what you want now.

Comment: Damn, that's contrived. (Obviously no fault of yours, that said.) However, it works perfectly so many, many thanks. :-)

Comment: @middaparka: indeed, it's a bit bizarre to have to go to those kind of lengths! The way I would *actually* solve this would probably be to do a search with Unix `find` or with the OS's file manager, and just refresh Eclipse after deleting the files. But at least we know there's some way to do it in Eclipse.